# Launch RDBMS Client GUIs from Delinea

Tags: permissions, credentials

I am using the delinea permission access management tool that I pointed to the application file of SSMS and it could launch my desired server instance with the secret server credentials configured on the tool. Is there a way to launch this for client tools like MySQL workbench and SQLyog targeting MySQL 5.7.x.